# Visual studio 2017 is running in admin mode

Tags: visual-studio-2017, admin

My visual studio 2017 is always running in administrator mode which I want to prevent. I don't want it to open always in admin mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the properties of **Visual Studio 2017** icon > Click **Advanced** :

[image]

Uncheck **Run as administrator** > Click **OK**

[image]

Now it will always open normal mode.